# logical OR and precedence

Tags: javascript

I've just been watching a tutorial which talked about the following if statement:

```
var a = 0;
if(a || a === 0){...};
```

It states that operator precedence means that `a === 0` is evaluated first, as it has a higher precedence than ||.

I've no real issue with that, but the tutorial goes on to say that 'a' is then evaluated -  but surely it's short-circuited?

I know it should be pretty simple, but I'm new to JS. Is this a mistake or am I misunderstanding what's being said?

Comment: Your tutorial is incorrect if it *really* says that. Issues of operator precedence are not the same as the order of operations in expression evaluation.

Comment: It will evaluate left to right. Left hand statement being false, the second being true

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought coming from Java, but I just assumed things must be different in JS. Nice one, thanks

Comment: technically it says "First it will run this triple equals function, and will say it's 'true'". which still seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test this easily enough with a getter. If `a` is true, the getter is called once, meaning that `obj.a === 0` is never evaluted due to short-circuiting:

```js
let obj =  {
    get a() {
        console.log("getting a")
        return true
    }
}
if(obj.a || obj.a === 0){
    console.log("true")
};
```

If `a` is falsey as is the case when `a` id `0` , both side are evaluated:

```js
let obj =  {
    get a() {
        console.log("getting a")
        return 0
    }
}
if(obj.a || obj.a === 0){
    console.log("true")
};
```

Comment: With `a` beinig 1 or a truthy value. You can just do `a || ++a` to see if it really short circuits. If right side doesn't get evaluated, then `a` is still 1, otherwise `a` is 2.

Answer (score 1):

No, the equivalence doesn't happen first:

```
var a = 0;
if(a || a === 0){...}
```

The `a` in this case is falsey and so the `||` continues onto the next statement, equivalent to:

```
if(a === 0){...}
```

At this point, the equivalence takes place and is clearly `true`, no short circuiting takes place because the expression is evaluated left to right.

---

The reason for this is that either side of the OR is a different expression and the expressions are evaluated from left to right.

```
expr1 || expr2
```

Once `expr1` has been evaluated, if it is truthy only then does short-circuiting take place and the expression as a whole be truthy. If this isn't the case `expr2` will be evaluated and if that is truthy then the expression as a whole will be truthy, otherwise it will be falsey.

Comment: oh, ok, so it does look at both sides of the logical OR and then evalutes  it?

Comment: No no no.  The right-hand expression is not evaluated at all if the left-hand expression is truthy.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but the right-hand side is definitely not evaluated first. The comparison of `a` to `0` only happens *after* `a` is determined not to be truthy.

Comment: @Pointy Ah, 2s, lemme rejig the answer

Comment: yeah, i learnt in java that it never looked at the other side at all, but this tutorial definitely says it's 'true'. so it's wrong. ok, thanks!

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, worst attempt at an answer ever -.-

Comment: Ha ha things like this can be hard to explain clearly. No worries.

Comment: @Pointy Can you confirm my addition to make sure it's not another brain-fart :)

Comment: Yes it looks fine now.